# What's the symbol $\circ$ called, and what does it mean?

Tags: terminology-and-notation

I see the quantum gate
$U_1^{-1}\circ U_1\circ U_0=U_0$, what is the $\circ$ called and mean?

Comment: can you share the link from where you get that.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.00752

Comment: Btw, sometimes the $\circ$ symbol is used to represent the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) between matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol $\circ$ is used in mathematics to denote the [composition of maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). In the linked paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.00752) it is used in this sense to denote the composition of quantum channels (e.g. in Eq. (1)). This is common practice.

However, you will often see $\mathcal{U}\mathcal{V}$ instead of $\mathcal{U}\circ\mathcal{V}$. This is a simplified notation resembling matrix multiplication $AB$ for matrices $A$ and $B$. Indeed, matrix multiplication is nothing but the composition of matrices seen as linear maps on a vector space. But it is very uncommon to write $A\circ B$ when dealing with matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the authors of this paper and thank you for your attention to our work.

Actually, we often use $\mathcal{U}$ to represent a quantum channel (a linear map from density matrix to density matrix, dimension is $4^N\times 4^N$)), and $U$ as a quantum gate or unitary transformation, whose dimension is $2^N\times 2^N$).